# find command in bash vs find command in cli

Tags: string, bash, command-line-interface

I need to accommodate spaces in filepaths. Why does "find" not work from the script, but works from the cli?

```
MyLaptop$ ./my-bash-script.sh

find: '/Sandbox/test folder/testfiles-good/ResidentFile_1.pcapng': No such file or directory

MyLaptop$ find '/Sandbox/test folder/testfiles-good/ResidentFile_1.pcapng'

/Sandbox/test folder/testfiles-good/ResidentFile_1.pcapng

Using echo find -f "'$line'"

output: find -f '/Sandbox/test folder/testfiles-good/ResidentFile_1.pcapng'
```

But in this case: `FOUND="$(find -f "'$line'")"`
it does not

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: I don't understand the question. What is `/my-bash-script.sh` what does the code look like in there? What is all of this that you are sharing with no commentary? What do you mean when you say "it does not". Is there an error? Unexpected results? It's also getting a little late in the day and I might be slower than usual.

Comment: It looks like you're using quotes wrong, but without a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), it's hard to tell for sure. But in general, nested quotes are probably wrong, and using `echo` to see what a command will do is incredibly misleading. Specifically, `echo somecommand` will show what the command looks like after its quotes, escapes, etc have been parsed, applied, *and removed*; if you see quotes in the output from `echo`, there's probably something wrong.

Comment: Since you did not show your script, we can't know what's wrong in it.

Comment: ` file=$LISTOFFILES

while IFS= read line

 do
 
 let "FILESTESTED+=1"
 FOUND=$(find -f "$line")
 
   # if file is not found, ignore the error
   exec 2> /dev/null

   # if file is found:
  
    if [ "$FOUND" == "$line" ]
     then
                          echo "FOUND: $line" >> $DELETED_REPORT
                          FILESIZE=$(find "$line" -exec ls -l {} \; |  awk '{ print $5 }')
  
     echo "SIZE is: $FILESIZE" >> $DELETED_REPORT
  
     let "SPACETOTAL= SPACETOTAL + FILESIZE"
     let "FILES_DELETED_COUNT+=1"
     cp "$line" $DUMPSTER
  fi
  
 done <$file`

Comment: Not sure why the mini-markdown doesn't work on the code, but this version works, as opposed to the original FOUND="$(find -f "'$line'")" it does not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case ...

> ```
> FOUND="$(find -f "'$line'")"
> ```

... you are asking `find` for a file whose name contains leading and trailing `'` characters.  That is unlikely to be what you intended.  Though it may look strange, this is probably what you meant:

```
FOUND="$(find -f "$line")"
```

The `"` characters inside the command substitution do not pair with those outside (and if they did then the original command substitution would be wrong a different way).  On the other hand, word splitting is not performed on the result of the command substitution when it is used on the right-hand side of a variable assignment, so you could also just use

```
FOUND=$(find -f "$line")
```